# Which is faster array_merge or array_splice to merge arrays?

Tags: php

Which is faster array_merge or array_splice to merge arrays?
(using array_splice to replace nothing with the 2nd array which has the effect of merging)

array_splice looks like it might use less array copying and as a result it might be faster. Is there any research on this point?

e.g.

```
array_splice($a1, count($a1), 0, $a2);
$a1 = array_merge($a1, $a2);
```

Comment: The 2 functions doing not the same. One merges arrays the other splices! So what do you want to know?

Comment: How about benchmarking it specifically *for your use case…?!*

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I assume he's using `array_splice()` without removing anything, just splicing the new array at the end.

Comment: @Barmar year you are right, i thing the OP should ignore it, its only micro-optimizing.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's right. Splicing without removing anything would have the effect of merging. Apologies for the lack of clarity in the question. I'll edit to make that clear. (even if it is a micro-optimisation question, the rating of -4 does seem a bit unwarranted)

Comment: Was very sad to find this question with -3, it's exactly what I just went to google myself out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arguments = ["arg1" => "111", "arg2" => "222", "arg3" => "333"];
```

Use `array_splice` = 3.273508 (in seconds)

```
for ($i=0; $i < 1000000; $i++) { 
   $arguments = ["arg1" => "111", "arg2" => "222", "arg3" => "333"];
   array_splice($arguments, 0, 0,[777]);
   $arguments = [];
}
```

Note*
`array_splice($arguments, count($arguments), 0,[777]);` Same time as  `array_splice($arguments, 0, 0,[777]);` = ~3.273508 (in seconds)

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 777
    [arg1] => 111
    [arg2] => 222
    [arg3] => 333
)
```

---

Use `array_merge` = 2.984012 (in seconds)

```
for ($i=0; $i < 1000000; $i++) { 

    $arguments = ["arg1" => "111", "arg2" => "222", "arg3" => "333"];
    $args = array_merge([777], $arguments);
    $arguments = [];
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 777
    [arg1] => 111
    [arg2] => 222
    [arg3] => 333
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`array_merge` has to check whether the input array has numeric or named keys, so it knows whether to append or merge. `array_splice` doesn't need to do this check.